# Select query in IF statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

In my MySql database, I want to create select query which should give output like this:

in my select query i want a column output as 1, if the column value present in a list returned by a select query else 0 .

Select col1,col2,
,IF col3 IN
((select col from tabl2 ),1,0)AS col5
from tbl1.

Thanks in Advance

```
SELECT col1, col2, 

    IF col3 IN ((select col from tabl2 ),1,0) AS col5 

FROM tbl1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IF and subquery in MySQL

```
SELECT table1.column1, table1.column2,

    (

        SELECT IF (
            (SELECT column3 FROM table1 WHERE column3 IN (SELECT column FROM table2)), 1, 0
        ) 

    ) AS column_output 

FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       CASE WHEN col3 IN (select col from tabl2)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS col5 
FROM tbl1
```

Specific for MySQL:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3 IN (select col from tabl2) AS col5 
FROM tbl1
```